# How to use Google Contacts API in meteor?

Tags: meteor, access-token, google-contacts-api

I am using meteor to create a webpage with a dropdown list of Google Groups to select from and once selected, the Google contacts will be displayed.

I am using HTTP.call POST to Google's API and testing with the accessToken from mongoDB but when I use that token after some time it expires.  I looked into implementing an authentication flow but it is getting very complicated since there is no sample code on Google for meteor.  I am new to nodeJS, Javascript and Meteor.  Am I going about this the wrong way?  How would I implement this in meteor?

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2?csw=1#expiration

Answer (score 3):

To deal with the expiration of the accessToken, you will need to obtain the refreshToken from Google. With this refreshToken, you can obtain a new accessToken whenever necessary via a simple HTTP POST to Google's API. [Here](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#offline) is the relevant documentation from Google. To obtain the refreshToken, you will need to request for offline access and may also need to force the approval prompt, as detailed in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27468270/meteor-accounts-ui-config-not-working-with-google).

```
forceApprovalPrompt: {google: true},
requestOfflineToken: {google: true},
```

I recommend achieving all of the above using Meteor's [HTTP package](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/http_call). All the tools are there. You've probably already figured it out:

```
  var result = HTTP.post(
    "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token",
    {
      params: {
        'client_id': config.clientId,
        'client_secret': config.secret,
        'refresh_token': user.services.google.refreshToken,
        'grant_type': 'refresh_token'
      }
  });

  //Do some error checking here

  var newAccessToken = result.data.access_token;
```

1. **refresh_token** - The refresh token returned from the authorization
   code exchange.
2. **client_id** - The client ID obtained from the
   Developers Console.
3. **client_secret** - The client secret obtained from
   the Developers Console.
4. **grant_type** - As defined in the OAuth 2.0
   specification, this field must contain a value of refresh_token.
5. **result.data** will be a JSON object with the following

   {
     "access_token":"1/fFBGRNJru1FQd44AzqT3Zg",
     "expires_in":3920,
     "token_type":"Bearer",
   }

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this package its a little wrapper that does auto refresh for you:
[here](https://github.com/percolatestudio/meteor-google-api)

I actually ended up building my own auth flow for with oauth handler because i needed to move away from a tokens linked to user profiles.