# Meteor Accounts.ui.config not working with Google

Tags: javascript, meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3, google-signin

I am simply trying to log in with Google and get the permissions for Calendar, etc. However, my code in the client only prompts user signing in for offline access. Why is it not asking for the calendars, etc.? Also, it is not forcing the approval prompt. I'm using ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3

```
Accounts.ui.config({
    requestPermissions: {
        google: 
        ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tasks'],
//      forceApprovalPrompt: {google: true}
    }, 
    forceApprovalPrompt: {google: true},
    requestOfflineToken: {google: true},
    passwordSignupFields: 'EMAIL_ONLY',
//      extraSignupFields: []
});
```

Following Meteor docs not helping, as I get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Accounts.ui.config: Invalid key: forceApprovalPrompt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the `forceApprovalPrompt` key which is not recognized by the package. If you remove the key, it will ask for the calendars, etc.

It seems to work when using the accounts-ui package instead, so apparently this is due to a missing feature in `ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3`.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Now, I need a similar Bootstrap 3 Accounts package that doesn't have the problem. Any suggestions? BTW, I have filed a Github issue with the authors of this package and now waiting for a response: https://github.com/ianmartorell/meteor-accounts-ui-bootstrap-3/issues/23