# Using Meteor, how do requestPermissions for Google Calendar with loginWithGoogle (without accounts-ui package)?

Tags: meteor, google-api, google-calendar-api, meteor-accounts, accounts

I am building a Meteor application that requires access to a logged in user's Google Calendar account.

Currently I have Google Sign in on my login form (along with native account login) working. A user can sign in successfully using their Google Account.

I achieved the above as follows:

I installed the `accounts-google` and `service-configuration` packages. I already had the `accounts-password` package installed.

Next, I created a file in `/server/lib/config` called `accounts.js` that contains the following:

```
 Meteor.startup(function () {
  // Add Google configuration entry
  ServiceConfiguration.configurations.update(
    {service: "google"},
    {
      $set: {
        clientId: "*****.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        loginStyle: "popup",
        secret: "*****"
      }
    },
    {upsert: true}
  );
});
```

This allows a user to click on the Sign in with Google button, which renders a popup and allows them to sign in. Afterwards they are redirected to my app.

**Now for (first) my question**: how can I `requestPermissions` (as mentioned [here](http://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts.html#Meteor-loginWith%3CExternalService%3E) in the official Accounts Docs) to access a user's Google Calendar? More specifically, where can I access the `Accounts.LoginWithGoogle()` method?

I have looked at other SO questions ([such as this)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27468270/meteor-accounts-ui-config-not-working-with-google) explaining how to do it. However, they all use the `accounts-ui` package.

**Also**, how can I use the Google `OAuth` token I get from authentication offline (say, pass it to a Python script or having access to it via a MongoDB call)?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the same options as in the question you [linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27468270/meteor-accounts-ui-config-not-working-with-google) to the `Meteor.loginWithGoogle` method.

Specifically, refer to this docs page: [docs](https://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts.html#Meteor-loginWith<ExternalService>)

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. I do have one question regarding `Meteor.loginWithGoogle` though. How do I implement it? Does it have to be in a specific location on the server/client? I have done fount the `Meteor.loginWithGoogle` method, but it is in the protected package files, which I cannot change. So I am assuming I have to implement it myself? I'm just unsure where/how to do this.

Comment: It is available on the client, once you add accounts-google package

Comment: Do I have to call the `Meteor.loginWithGoogle' when the user signs in? If so, how do I link it to the Sign In with Google button that appeared automatically on the sign in page? I have created a client side .js script with a `Meteor.loginWithGoogle` method, however, when I Sign in with Google, I do not get a prompt asking for permissions to Google Calendar (as specified in the `loginWithGoogle` method).